how to use mongoaudit in cli only and give me report file
how to use mongoaudit using only CLI and give me the report or send it to email by only using CLI and not the GUI
I tried this
"mongoaudit --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 > mongoaudit_report3.txt"
but mongoaudit_report3.txt is empty
i want it to give me the report
